# Una consulta. ¿Cómo inicializo en un método de VB.Net un parámetro opcional tipo Point?

Tags: vb.net, parámetros

Vengo en son de paz. Cualquier respuesta es bienvenida.

Declaro un parámetro opcional tipo Point, así:

```
Function PuntoActual(ByRef Optional XY As Point = Nothing)
...
End Function
```

Me gustaría asignarle un punto por defecto como New Point(0, 0) pero como no es una constante no se puede. También se podría separar en sus componentes x, y, pero no me gustaría dividirlo en dos parámetros.

El problema es que si hago esta comparación para saber si no se ingresó el parámetro (porque es opcional):

```
If XY = Nothing Then
  'Aquí se controlaría cuando no se ingresa un parámetro.
End If
```

Aunque no se genera error, nunca detecta XY como Nothing, es decir no fluye por allí la ejecución. Tampoco funciona el operador Is en lugar de =.

Entonces, la consulta es: Cómo le asigno un valor que pueda comparar para saber que no se ingresó parámetro o cómo hago la comparación en este caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi si me funciona perfectamente el `if`

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    PuntoActual() 'NULO
    PuntoActual(New Point()) 'NULO
    PuntoActual(New Point(3, 7)) 'BIEN
End Sub

Function PuntoActual(ByRef Optional XY As Point)
    If XY = Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("NULO")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("BIEN")
    End If
    Return 0
End Function
```

Por otro lado, puedes hacer que el opcional sea (0,0) usando Polimorfismo paramétrico

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    PuntoActual() 'NULO
    PuntoActual(New Point()) 'NULO
    PuntoActual(New Point(3, 7)) 'BIEN
End Sub

Function PuntoActual(ByRef XY As Point)
    If XY = Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("NULO")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("BIEN")
    End If
    Return 0
End Function

Function PuntoActual()
    Return PuntoActual(New Point(0, 0))
End Function
```

Es decir creas una función con el mismo nombre pero sin argumentos que crea el punto (0,0) y se lo pasa a la función con argumentos

Comment: Sí gracias. Tienes razón, sí funcionaba. Había un problema en la lógica de mi código.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen. Acabo de comprobar que:

```
If XY = Nothing Then
  'Aquí se controlaría cuando no se ingresa un parámetro.
End If
```

Sí funciona (había un problema en mi código).